# jquery ui tooltips on <li> vs <option> elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to understand the assignment of jquery ui tooltips.

I have a simple code snippet below, trying to apply tool tips to `<li>` and `<option>` elements.  I don't understand why the same approach doesn't work for both.  See below

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p></p>
<div id="ctnr2">
  <select>
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS

```
var content_dict = {
  'Item 1': 'Eins',
  'Item 2': 'To',
  'Item 3': 'Tres',
  'Item 4': 'Qatre',
  'Item 5': 'Vijf',
};

$(function() {
  //List items tooltip
  $('#container').tooltip({
    items: 'li',
    track: true,
    content: function() {
      return "tooltip: " + content_dict[$(this).text()];
    }
  });

  //Select options tooltips
  $('#ctnr2').tooltip({
    items: 'select, option',
    track: true,
    content: function() {
      return "tooltip: " + content_dict[$(this).text()];
    }
  });
});
```

The tooltips show up on the list items and on the `<select>` tag but not on the options within the select.

1. What about the `<option>`'s is different from jquery's perspective?
2. How do I properly implement tooltips on the `<option>`'s as in the list items?

[JS fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mosarani/bxtrv1um/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with `jQuery-UI` or its tooltips. It only has to do with `<option>`s and their inability to be targeted by pointer events. As you can see...

```js
$('select')
  .on(
    'hover mouseenter mouseover click focus mouseout tap pan blur dblclick', 
    'option', 
    function(e){
      console.log(e, arguments);
    }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>Option one</option>
  <option>Option two</option>
  <option>Option three</option>
  <option>... and so on</option>
</select>
```

..., all `pointer events` (the list is longer) are off-limits on `<option>`s.

Options, for what it's worth, are one of the biggest failures of `HTML`. Nobody really knows why but, when they were invented, someone came up with  the concept they are somewhat special and should be styled by the OS, according to user preferences regarding input elements (older versions of Windows actually allowed you to pick colors for selects, including border and background-color, hover state details and styles, and all sorts of other details - this was all done in OS theme and it applied to theme controls and to (some) form elements in web pages).

The result is what you see today: the only way to style them cross-browser is to hide them completely and simulate their behavior using other, more controllable `HTML` elements (like `<div>`s). This is what every single `<select>` styling library does (chosen, select2, autocomplete, bootstrap select, selectize, etc...).

In conclusion, there is absolutely no way you could *"properly implement tooltips on the `<option>`s"*, as you nicely put it. Unless you replace the `<option>`s with `<div>`s, or `<span>`s, using any library mentioned above..

Comment: Very helpful explanation.  I hadn't ever encountered this before.  Thanks!